# monitor variable value within class object WITHOUT watch windows and WITHOUT OnTime call, in VBA

Tags: vba

Hello I am looking to see if there is a way to monitor and execute code when a variable in a class object has changed value during run time.

Here is one way I tried to pull it off....

Create this class:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private p_bVarToMonitor As Boolean
Public Property Get bVarToMonitor() As Boolean
    bVarToMonitor = p_bVarToMonitor
End Property
Public Property Let bVarToMonitor(v As Boolean)

    p_bVarToMonitor = v
    If v = False Then
        GoTo bVarToMonitorFalse
    End If

End Property
```

Then test it in a module (not in the class module):

```
Sub test()

Dim m As clsVarMonitorBoolean
Set m = New clsVarMonitorBoolean

m.bVarToMonitor = False 'this should make it goto bVarToMonitorFalse:

'Code to skip when bVarToMonitor = False

Exit Sub
bVarToMonitorFalse:

'other alternative code to run when bVarToMonitor = False

End Sub
```

...however, it doesn't work because the goto label is in a different module. Note, I need to use the class object in a regular code module, not within the same class module.

**Update:**

If I can't do this I have to do something like this

```
test()
Dim b As Boolean
b = SomeFunctionCall(input1)
if b = False then
  goto altcode
end if
b = SomeFunctionCall(input1)
if b = False then
  goto altcode
end if
b = SomeFunctionCall(input2)
if b = False then
  goto altcode
end if
b = SomeFunctionCall(input3)
if b = False then
  goto altcode
end if
'etc....repeat serveral times
end Sub
```

I.e. I have to do a ton of if statements throughout the code for each input to SomeFunctionCall.

Comment: Seems it would be easier to just check the value of m.bVarToMonitor in the module where you need to evaluate.  It's actually less lines of code because you can get rid of that check in the properties Let AND you can replace bVarToMonitorFalse: with an IF statement to check the value.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing in reality; however, in this case the way I am using it I have to type out out a lot of if statements...one after each time I set the variable. Wondering if there is a better way like setting the variable each time and allow the class to change execution when the variable is a certain value. I'll add this to my question. Thanks.

Comment: You can do this by raising en event. Try reading up on it a bit, actually this beats the crap out of me, but maybe you will have the patience to experiment and understand: [Raising events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)